# Existence of a surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image][click here for the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Vne.png)

I cannot have an approach to this question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would argue using the characterization of the finite abelian groups and the first isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: If you are familiar with vector spaces over arbitrary fields but have not covered enough of the general structure (that Chris Custer's argument relies on a bit), then here's a hint for you. Do you see why $K_1\times\cdots\times K_m$ has a quotient group isomorphic to $C_p^m$? That is, a vector space $V$ of dimension $m$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Can you then show how the existence of a homomorphism of the prescribed type implies that the vector space $V$ is generated by $n$ vectors? In violation of basic linear algebra.

Comment: Pictures of text are [generally not appropriate here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Please instead use MathJax - [here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The only way that the product of two $p$-groups can be written as one cyclic group is if the orders are relatively prime, by the Chinese remainder theorem.

So, if you look at $C_{p^r}\times C_{q^s}\cong C_{p^rq^s}$, the RHS is not a $p$-group.

Comment: But how does this helps here @ChrisCuster

Comment: Well, by the first isomorphism theorem, we would have that $K_1\times\dots\times K_m$ would be the quotient of a product of _fewer_ $p$-groups.  Because a quotient of a product of $p$-groups with $n$ factors is a product of $p$-groups with at most $n$ factors.

Comment: I think I got your point here, Although the edit you have just made in your answer doesn't ring any bell, I mean that possibility can not occur as all the Hi and Kj are p-cyclic only, right?@ChrisCuster

Comment: Yes, but then, if I get your meaning, we have something like $C_{p^r}\times C_{p^s}$, which can't be 'combined'. @DevendraSinghRana  That is, there is no surjection from $C_{p^{r+s}}$, because that would imply cyclicity.

Comment: Oh, Ok you were just stating the theorem, I thought you were talking in the sense of above question. Thnx, Everything is clear for me now @ChrisCuster

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thank you, I understood the solution.